# 301 Redirection for a New URL in New Website

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect

I have a **internal page** in example.com with around 10,000 organic traffic per month, but I am not making any money from it.

I am building a new blog called example2.com in near future with monetizing plan. I have plan to create a **very similar kind** of post and put 301 ridirect from example1.com/old-post to example2.com/new post.

I use 301 redirection only for that post. If I do it, can I still get those 10k (at least 80%) organic traffic for my new site?

Comment: *...can I still get those 10k (at least 80%) organic traffic for my new site?* Only for a while. This would only be a temporary effect until the search engines index the new page. This assumes a 301 redirect. A 302 will not help you.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks. When search engine index new page, can't I get at least 50-80% traffic for new page? Or will I lost the all traffic?

Comment: You will get the traffic that the new page deserves.

Comment: New page will be more quality than new page... I think you mean different thing.... New website have low backlink, low age, etc.... Those will affect?????

Comment: *New website have low backlink, low age, etc.... Those will affect?????* Yes. But time is your friend.

Comment: Keep in mind that any links to the original page will retain it's value and pass the value to the new page as long as the 301 redirect remains. In time, new links to the new page will make it possible to remove the 301 and old page if you want. Cheers!!